# tensorflow - normalizing vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a vector that looks something like `[0, 0.2, 0, 0.24, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.12]`. Is there a single operator in tensorflow that will normalize this vector so that the values range between 0 and 1 (where 0.24 is 1).

I will not know the max value before hand (ie 0.24). The range is fairly arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `tf.math.l2_normalize`

```
arr = [0, 0.2, 0, 0.24, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.12]
norm = tf.math.l2_normalize(arr)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(norm))
```

output

```
[0., 0.38348246, 0., 0.46017894, 0., 0., 0.7669649, 0.23008947]
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/l2_normalize

Answer (score 1):

Check tensorflow_transform.scale_to_0_1 function, tensorflow_transform is the api for applying different type of transformation during training and prediction.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/scale_to_0_1

Answer (score 0):

You can check in tensorflow documentation about that but you can easily implement a min max normalization or z-score normalization using standard deviation and mean from numpy lib or scipy

This is for numpy arrays but you can get the idea

```
# min-max mormalization
def normalize(X):
    col_max = np.max(X, axis=0)
    col_min = np.min(X, axis=0)
    normX = np.divide(X - col_min, col_max - col_min)
    return normX
```